# How to visite static files in Nginx server?

Tags: nginx

I have installed nginx in my Ubuntu system server.When I visit my server ip,it shows default page.And then I rewrite the files 'nginx.conf',the code like this:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/website/;
        try_files index.html = 404;
    }
}
```

I just want to visit static fiels,Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my setting?

Comment: What happens after changing your configuration to the given code? Still showing the default page or are you getting any errors? Did you reload the config after changing it? `service nginx reload` should do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have solved this problem by changing the server_name,just like that:  ```server_name my ip```.Finally I uploaded my files and visited it successfully.